# Access a button that is placed in long nested div containers

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to access a button directly (I do not think there is a way) in my JavaScript code which is placed in a long nested div containers as shown below. Is there an easy way that my button element can be found with a name and I do not have to call each div to go to my button?

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="true" title="myFile" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0px; display: block;">
<div class="1">
  <div class="2"> 
    <div class="3"> 
     <div class="4">
      <div class="5">
       <div class="6"> 
         <div class="7"> 
           <div class="8">
           <button  class="myButton" type="button"> </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
           </div> 
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</iframe>
```

JS

```
function AccessButton() {  

    var bt = document.getElementsByClassName("myButton");
}  

AccessButton();
```

EDIT: I am sorry I forgot an extremely important thing. The whole code is present inside an iframe div.

Comment: The only problem is that you use `.getElementById()` although the button has no id. Either make the class an id or use `.getElementsByClassName()` or `.querySelector()`

Comment: Sorry yes I did not see that. So I should be doing ```document.getElementsByClassName("myButton")```?

Comment: If there's only one element with that class then use `.querySelector()` and skip the collection part

Comment: Does your page only have one of those buttons?

Comment: Sorry guys I updated my question. I forgot to add iframe tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `querySelector` here, it will find the first element in the document that matches the CSS selector passed to it:

```js
function AccessButton() {
  document.querySelector(".a1 .myButton").click();
}

AccessButton();
```

```html
<div class="a1">
  <div class="a2">
    <div class="a3">
      <div class="a4">
        <div class="a5">
          <div class="a6">
            <div class="a7">
              <div class="a.a1 8">
                <button class="myButton" type="button" onclick="console.log('clicked')">MyButton</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please note that [CSS classes must not start with a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors).